# Codeigniter how to add a link to html table class displaying db query

Tags: database, codeigniter, class, hyperlink, html-table

I'm busy designing a web page using Codeigniter and I'm using the html table class to display the results of a db query.

I want to add a link to the db results using the html table class to delete or edit a record.

Please if somebody has done this before please help me.

Comment: Some code might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comment I decided that I would post my solution.

I would like to know if there is a way that I can get codeigniter to generate the same table with the links below using the table class

View

```
<table border="1" title="User information" id="table">
        <caption><b>User information</b></caption>
    <thead>
    <tr><th>E-mail address</th><th>Name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Home address</th>
    <th>Postel address</th><th>Mobile number</th><th>Home telephone</th><th>ID number</th>
    <th>Action</th></tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody> 
    <?php

        foreach($results as $row){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->email . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->name . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->lastname . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->homeaddress . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->posteladdress . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->mobile  . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->hometel  . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->idnum . "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='" . base_url() . "index.php/user_admin/get_user_edit/$row->id'>Edit</a> &nbsp<a href='" . base_url() . "index.php/user_admin/suspend/$row->id' >Suspend</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
    }

    ?>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```